# Convert Stored procedure result from NULL to 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have temp table accepting result set of executing stored proc. I can't change stored proc. The sp return null columns in some rows but I want to convert NULL to 0 when insert them into the temp table. How to do it easily?

My SQL is like:

```
Insert into #temp (co1, co2, co3)
exec sp_xxx
```

co3 from sp_xxx might be NULL, but I want to convert it to 0 and store in #temp.col3

Comment: There is no good way of doing this. For a non temporary table you could use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger but not possible on a `#temp` table. If you can't change the stored procedure then maybe easiest thing would be to add a computed column that does the desired conversion and reference that instead? Well [I suppose you could always use this technique](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1228165/73226) but seems completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 5):

Give it a try,

```
ISNULL(COLUMN_NAME, 0)
```

Comment: I did like this: Insert into #temp (co1, co2, ISNULL(co3,0)) exec sp_xxx

Incorrect syntax error got.

Comment: You can do one thing, after inserting in `#temp` get the result from `#temp` as SELECT co1,co2,ISNULL(co3,0) AS co3 FROM #temp. Let me workout more on this, if i get anything as your requirement i'll get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Insert into #temp (co1, co2, co3);
    exec sp_xxx;
```

-- update value where column have null value :

```
  update #temp set col1=isnull(col1,0), col2=isnull(col2,0), col3=isnull(col3,0)
     where (col1 is null) or (col2 is null) or (col3 is null)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create temp table with 3 more comuputed columns value of which is based on your current columns..

Example below..

```
CREATE TABLE #Products 
(
    ProductID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
  , QtyAvailable smallint
  , UnitPrice money
  , InventoryValue AS isnull(QtyAvailable,0)
)

insert into #Products(QtyAvailable,UnitPrice)
values (null,10),(20,10)

select * from #Products
```

In the above example InventoryValue is the computed column and value is populated based on QtyAvailable value..

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is a reasonable option.

Answer (score 0):

As Vikram says, after retrieving the data into your temp table you can then update the values accordingly. if it is just column3 that could be null then

```
UPDATE #temp
SET col3 = 0 
WHERE col3 IS NULL
```

will do this just fine.

Otherwise you could just do the ISNULL check when you select back from your temp table and use the information later on

```
SELECT ISNULL(col3, 0)
FROM #temp
```